# Linking with mapreduce libraries automatically

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce

I am working on a mapreduce program (it is actually a rather complicated wordcount algorithm) running on amazon web services. I generated a .jar to run on the AWS nodes. What I am doing now is incorporating all mapreduce library jars into my .jar file. Everything works fine but I suppose this is not a very good practice (they did some updates of their machine images and I am getting strange exceptions which could be related to this). Can someone explain me how I could automatically link with the hadoop version installed on amazon so I could do without adding the external library to my jar?

Thx alot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're using Amazons Elastic MapReduce !? 
There are different ami-versions with different hadoop versions available, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-ami.html#emr-default-versions.

The hadoop jars itself + it 3rd party dependencies (like commons-io e.g.) are already in the classpath of your job. So you're right, it could make problems if you bundling hadoop jars with annother version to your job-jar.
So i would say you could:
- determine which hadoop version you're booting (based on the ami-version)
- determine what are the libraries used in that hadoop version (either inspect the running ec2 instances or download the hadoop version from [apache website](http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/))
- compile you program again the right hadoop and exclude all hadoop and hadoops-3rd party jars when you bundle the fat jar

Comment: Hi, at first I tried to package as a runnable jar using eclipse, now I noticed there's also the option of packaging as a jar (with a main class selected). This way I could exclude the hadoop jars. On AWS everything worked flawlessly, thx again!